# converting jquery to mootools on small script that equalizes heights

Tags: jquery, mootools, javascript

i have this small script that makes boxes equal heights that i use all the time in jQuery that i need to convert to mootools for a site. 
in this example the boxes would be floated left at thirds with style sheets.

```
<div id="box1" class="equals">content here</div>
<div id="box2" class="equals">content here</div>
<div id="box3" class="equals">content here</div>



       jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var highestCol = Math.max(jQuery('#box1').height(),jQuery('#box2').height(),jQuery('#box3').height());
 jQuery('.equals').height(highestCol);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably better to make it modular and reusable:

```
var equalElements = function(els) {
    // make elements equal height to max height of the set.
    els.setStyle("height", Math.max.apply(Math, els.map(function(el) { return el.getSize().y })));
};

equalElements(document.getElements("div.equals"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/TxtBQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
  var highestCol = Math.max($('box1').getSize().y, $('box2').getSize().y, $('box3').getSize().y);
  $$('.equals').setStyle('height', highestCol);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that can equalize height/width, set if it should resize to the biggest/smallest element: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/5uQEP/

Pretty simple usage:

```
document.getElements('li').equalize({
    dir: 'height',
    mode: 'max'
});
```

You can also return the raw value and do some animation:

```
var maxHeight = document.getElements('li').equalize({
    dir: 'height',
    mode: 'max',
    raw: true
});

document.getElements('li').tween('height', maxHeight);
```